# Storing email into mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I am encountering a really strange bug.

```
for emailid in item_ids:
    resp, data = conn.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)") 
    try: 
        db.emails.insert({'raw': data})
```

So I am fetching a bunch of data from gmail using oauth2.clients.imap. After fetching the email from gmail, I have decided to store it as "raw" first in my mongodb.

And then in another part of my script, I do something like this:

```
for i,j in enumerate(db.emails.find()):
    raw_s = j['raw'][0][1] 
    email = email_module.message_from_string(raw_s)
    if email.is_multipart():
        print get_cleaned_body(email)
```

*note that I did a `import email as email_module` and shadowed the variable email as I cannot think of a better term for a variable to hold an email instance*

Now the strange this is, none of my email instances are multipart!

If i modify my retrieval code to be:

```
for emailid in item_ids:
    resp, data = conn.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)") 
    try: 
        #db.emails.insert({'raw': data})
        e = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
        print e.is_multipart()
```

I am seeing a few `True`s.

I guess one possible explanation for this might be that saving the data into mongodb messes up something which doesn't allow the email to be parse correctly?

Comment: What does the data look like in mongo? Presumably when you receive a multipart email it isn't plain text, yet you are saving it into mongo as plain text.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you should do this:

oid = db.emails.insert({'raw': bson.binary.Binary(data)})

Saving in binary ensures that the original content of the data is not changed.